# What do all the options on GetOptions mean?

Tags: tfs

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.getoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) lists four options, with limited explanation:

- Overwrite "Overwrite existing writable files if they conflict with the downloaded files." Does this apply to all files, or just ones we've told TFS we've edited?
- GetAll "Gets all files." What files does TFS not normally get?
- Preview "Executes a get without modifying the disk." This one seems pretty clear.
- Remap "Remaps existing items on the disk to the server items where the content and disk location are not changing." I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 3):

**Overwrite**:  will blindly overwrite writable files that you *have not* pended for edit.  If you have marked a file as 'writable' then you have violated the contract with TFS and it assumes that you have done this for a good reason (eg, modifying the file without taking a checkout, because you were working offline).  This will generally produce a writable conflict on the file, but if you specify this flag, then the writable file will be overwritten.

This only applies to server workspaces (local workspaces are always writable).  This has no effect on files that you *have* pended for edit.  Get will always produce conflicts for files that are edited locally and updated on the server; if you want to update files that are checked out, you must undo the checkout (or resolve the conflict with `TakeTheirs`).

**Get All**:  will download every file and update it, even if TFS believes that the local version is the same as the remote version and that downloading a new version would be a noop.  TFS tracks every version that you have locally, as well as remotely, so this is only useful if you edit files locally without checking them out.

If you have kept them writable, then then - as mentioned above - this will be a writable conflict.  If you have then marked them read-only then TFS assumes that you *have not* made any changes and will not bother updating them when you do a get (because it knows the file contents haven't changed).  If you have manually changed the file contents, then marking this will update those files to the server version.

**Preview**:  will just fire events and provide results that indicate what *would* be downloaded with the given parameters.

**Remap**:  is a clever option that allows you to perform an in-place branch switching (which is very common with some version control systems that branch at the repository level - like Git - but somewhat complicated in TFVC.)

Consider that you have mapped `$/Foo/main` to `C:\Foo`, and done a get latest.  If you update your working folder mappings so that `$/Foo/branches/feature` now points to `C:\Foo`, then issue a get with `Remap`, then the server will download only the changed files between `main` and `branches/feature`, so it's an inexpensive way to update your local workspace to a feature branch.

(If you're looking for an example, this functionality exists in the command-line interface and in [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx) but not in Visual Studio.)

Comment: Thank you. So, if I have a local workspace, and (unknown) files have got unintentionally changed, I would have to use both Overwrite and GetAll to restore them?

Comment: @MarkRaymond Yes that should be correct - although if you have *new files* hanging out in your workspace, those would not be affected.